# How to target movie clip on the stage from doc class AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, movieclip, flash-ide

I am making  dynamic drag and drop game.
I have a class for the dragged items containing the drag drop code.

My problem is I can't call/access the movie clips I've already put on the stage in my hit test statement.

Here is my code and target1_mc & target2_mc are the existing movie clips on the stage:

```
package {
 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 import flash.events.MouseEvent;
 import flash.text.TextField;




 public class recipeMC extends MovieClip {



  private var startX:Number;
  private var startY:Number;
  private var counter:Number=0;




  public function recipeMC() {
   this.mouseChildren = false;
   this.buttonMode = true;
   this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUp);
   this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropIt);
  }
  private function pickUp(event:MouseEvent):void {
   this.startDrag(true);
   this.parent.addChild(this);
   startX = this.x;
   startY = this.y;

  }
  private function dropIt(event:MouseEvent):void {
   this.stopDrag();



   *****if (this.hitTestObject(target1_mc)
   ||this.hitTestObject(target2_mc) )***** {
    this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickUp);
    this.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropIt);
    this.buttonMode = false;
    this.x = myTarget.x;
    this.y = myTarget.y;
    counter++;
   } else {
    //reply_txt.text = "Try Again!";
    this.x = startX;
    this.y = startY;
   }

  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to publish settings->flash->settings(button) and select "Automatically declare stage instances." That should do the trick.

**EDIT**

Try this inside your recieptMovieClip class:

```
MovieClip(root).target1_mc
MovieClip(root).target2_mc
```

Because this is annoying to type you can store MovieClip(root) in a variable. It's important to note that the root property doesn't exist unless your movieClip is on the display list. So until your class has been added wth addChild() this will not work.

An alternative method is to use a document class and store a reference to the main timeline in a static variable. I wrote a blog post about that once. [Have a look](http://actionsnippet.com/?p=657)

If you use the technique in that blogpost you could access the main timeline from anywhere like this:

```
Main.display.target1_mc
```

Hope that helps. I can upload an example or two if you need them.

Comment: it is selected but still i have the same problem

Comment: the error appears said that "access of undefined property target1_mc"

Comment: are you sure that you gave the movieClip the instance name target1_mc? Maybe you should upload your files somewhere so that we can take a look.

Comment: yes i am sure they have these names ,but this is not the doc class i am sorry i misunderstand , it is a custom class.does this makes a different???